# React Dropdown Select Initialization and getting results back for key of displayed text

Tags: mysql, reactjs, select, dropdown

I am new to React.
In an effort to assign a CpyMasterID (MySql key) to a User I am using a React Dropdown Select. I can get it to display a list of Company keys (from the MySQL dbase).

What I need it to do is display the Company Name of the assigned company (if the userscpymasterId is not null) and return the associated cpymasterid if a Company Name is selected.
[Bottom of CreateUserSmallComponent Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekQru.jpg)

Here is my existing code.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import UserService from '../Services/UserService';
    import CpyMasterService from '../Services/CpyMasterService';
    
        class CreateUserSmallComponent extends Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props)
        
                this.state = {
                    isLoading:true,
                    isReadOnly:false,
                    userId: this.props.match.params.userId,
                    usersfirstName: '',
                    userslastName: '',
                    userscpymasterId: '',
                    cpymaster: []
                }
                this.saveOrUpdateUser = this.saveOrUpdateUser.bind(this);
            }
            componentDidMount(){
                CpyMasterService.getCpyMaster().then((res) => {
                    this.setState({ cpymaster: res.data});
               });
        
           if(this.state.userId === '_add'){
                    return
                }else{
                    UserService.getUserById(this.state.userId).then( (res) =>{
                        let user = res.data;
                        this.setState({isLoading:false});
                        this.setState({usersfirstName: user.usersfirstName,
                            userslastName: user.userslastName,
                            userscpymasterId: user.userscpymasterId
                        });
                    });
                }        
            }
            saveOrUpdateUser = (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                let user = {usersfirstName: this.state.usersfirstName, 
                    userslastName: this.state.userslastName, 
                    userscpymasterId: this.state.userscpymasterId
                    };
                    if(this.state.userId === '_add'){
                        UserService.createUser(user).then(res =>{
                            this.props.history.push('/users');
                        });
                    }else{
                         UserService.updateUser(user, this.state.userId).then( res => {
                             this.props.history.push('/users');
                    });
                }
            }
            
            changeFirstNameHandler= (event) => {
                this.setState({usersfirstName: event.target.value});
            }
        
            changeLastNameHandler= (event) => {
                this.setState({userslastName: event.target.value});
            }
        
            changeUsersCpyMasterIdHandler= (event) => {
                this.setState({userscpymasterId: event.target.value});
            }
        
            cancel(){
                this.props.history.push('/users');
            }
        
            getTitle(){
                if(this.state.userId === '_add'){
                    return <h3 className="text-center">Add User</h3>
                }else{
                    return <h3 className="text-center">Update User</h3>
                }
            }
        
            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        {this.state.isLoading &&
                        <h4>Getting Data....</h4>
                        }
                        <br></br>
                           <div className = "container">
                                <div className = "row">
                                    <div className = "card col-md-6 offset-md-3 offset-md-3">
                                        {
                                            this.getTitle()
                                        }
                                        <div className = "card-body">
                                            <form>
                                                <div className = "form-group">
                                                    <label> First Name: </label>
                                                    <input placeholder="First Name" name="usersfirstName" className="form-control" 
                                                        readOnly = {this.state.isReadOnly} value={this.state.usersfirstName} onChange={this.changeFirstNameHandler}/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className = "form-group">
                                                    <label> Last Name: </label>
                                                    <input placeholder="Last Name" name="userslastName" className="form-control" 
                                                        readOnly = {this.state.isReadOnly} value={this.state.userslastName} onChange={this.changeLastNameHandler}/>
                                                </div>
        
                                                <div>
                                                    <select>
                                                        <option selected disabled = "true" > -- Select CpyMaster -- </option>
                                                        {
                                                            this.state.cpymaster.map((x,y)=> (<option key={x}>{y}</option>))
                                                        }
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <button className="btn btn-success" disabled={this.state.isReadOnly} onClick={this.saveOrUpdateUser}>Save</button>
                                                <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.cancel.bind(this)} style={{marginLeft: "10px"}}>Cancel</button>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
        
                           </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }
        
        export default CreateUserSmallComponent
```

I thank all for input to help move me forward on this one.

Company Master Format

```
    public class CpyMaster {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long cpymasterid;
        
        @Column(name = "cpymastername")
        private String  cpymasterName;
    
        @Column(name = "cpymasteraddress1")
        private String  cpymasterAddress1;
        
        @Column(name = "cpymasteraddress2")
        private String  cpymasterAddress2;
        
        @Column(name = "cpymastercity")
        private String  cpymasterCity;
        
        @Column(name = "cpymasterzip")
        private String  cpymasterZip;
    
        @Column(name = "cpymasterdocumentfolder")
        private String  cpymasterdocumentFolder;
    
        @Column(name = "cpymastercreated")
        private String  cpymasterCreated;
    
        @Column(name = "cpymasterupdated")
        private String  cpymasterUpdated;
        
        @Column(name = "states_statesid")
        private String  states_statesId;
    
        public long getCpymasterid() {
            return cpymasterid;
        }
```

Comment: What's the structure of cpymaster ? Seems like your code is very close and you just need to use the appropriate variables in the option tag (such as "value=").

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Here is the cpy master:
Added to original post :-)

Comment: Thank you for your interest, hoping you can assist. Here is the cpy master: Added to original post :-) – @talfreds

Comment: I actually meant the structure of "res.data" that you assign to the cpymaster state value.

Comment: Well I had some code in there and commented it out.
Current code is:
'''
    componentDidMount(){
        CpyMasterService.getCpyMaster().then((res) => {
            this.setState({ cpymaster: res.data});
       });
'''

If I replace it with:

'''
    CpyMasterService.getCpyMaster().then((res) => {
        let cpymaster = res.data;
         this.setState({
              cpymasterId: cpymaster.cpymasterId,
              cpymasterName: cpymaster.cpymasterName
             });
        });
'''

Would it help to access the data? Sounds like it would help. @talfreds

Comment: Both should be fine. What I want to check is that a) that you are actually getting the data from your fetch and b) the way that data is structured so you can correctly use it in the map() function

Comment: I added a snippit of the botton of the CreateUserSmallComponent  rendering to the orignal post so you can see what is currently displayed. I see the Id. I would like to see the Company Name and have access to the Id for the MySql update as a foreign key. @talfreds

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works. Original post was selecting the key value for the cpymaster, this example is the same concept, but references the States array (1-Florida, 2=Georgia, etc.).

...

> ```
>                                         <select onChange={this.changeCpyMasterStateSelectHandler}
>                                         value={this.state.states_statesId} style={{marginLeft: "10px"}}>
>                                             <option selected disabled = "true"  > -- Select State -- </option>
>                                                 {
>                                                  this.state.states.map((item,index)=> (<option key={index}
> ```
>
> value={item.statesid}>{item.statesName} ))
> }

```
                                     </select>
```

...